# Why isn't IE11 providing me with a stack trace?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, stack-trace

I'm running a VM with Windows 7 to run IE11 for browser compatibility testing.

I'm encoutering IE11 specific errors, but none of them seem to have stack traces, I'm just getting generic errors which is making it extremely difficult to diagnose the issue. See image:

[image: IE11 with no stack trace]

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like an XMLHttpRequest syntax error, please check the related code. Besides, I suggest checking this code on another browser (such as: Edge or Chrome) and check whether having the same error.

Comment: Whilst there is no stack trace, there is nothing that I can see to suggest it is an issue with any XMLHttpRequest. Really, there is no way to tell much given the lack of information, which is the source of the question in the first place. As the question specifies, they are IE11 specific bugs, so they do not occur in other browsers - otherwise the fix would be easy.